# How could I make a report in different columns? Odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

good afternoon. I would like you to help us with a report. Here bellow I will show you what I have till now.
[image]

and here again Ii will show you what I need.

[image]

So, I want to have six (6 report) in one page but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use t-foreach inside `<div class="page">Here</div>` to get all records in a page, After that you can design tamplate by table.

For example print product barcode on a single page.

```
<template id="report_productbarcode">
    <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
        <div class="page">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="product">
                <t t-call="product.report_simple_barcode">
                    <t t-set="product" t-value="product"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: Ashwin, would you have an example or something like that? I have not gotten it yet.

Comment: @MauriSadaniowski Here you'll get an example that is send you above is already in addon of odoo14.

[link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/cd9c071c9357cef14635ef094a9f14fc5431956c/addons/product/report/product_product_templates.xml)